# Pip is trying to build numpy instead of taking pre-built versions on M1 Mac

Tags: python, macos, numpy, apple-m1

I have an M1 mac where I was trying to do some workarounds to install numpy from a build.  I wasn't able to get any to work but now I'm trying to do a "standard install" while running a terminal using Rosetta.

When I do so the output looks like the following

```
MacBook-Pro ~ pip install numpy                
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.20.1.zip (7.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517) ... error
```

After this is a bunch of output where it ultimately fails to build.  I don't want it to try and build but want it to take the pre-built installs that are ready to go.  I'm sure I did some configuration somewhere that is causing this but is there any way to undo it?

Another thing I don't quite understand is that I've nuked the pip cache so I don't even know where it's getting this "cached numpy" from

I know I'm using the right architecture given the following

```
MacBook-Pro ~ uname -m                              
x86_64
```

**UPDATE**
Also tried running to force to only use binary with the following, still with no luck

```
MacBook-Pro ~/Downloads pip install numpy --only-binary=:
all:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

Adding version info as FYI

```
MacBook-Pro  ~  python --version                1 ↵  py3
Python 3.9.1
MacBook-Pro  ~  pip --version                     ✔  py3
pip 21.0.1 from /Users/<>/py3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

I'll also note that I'm using a venv and that my python install was installed with the native ARM homebrew version

Comment: just curious, why does `uname -m` show `x86_64` on an apple m1? why isn't it showing arm64?

Comment: Because I'm running the terminal w/ Rosetta

Answer (score 2):

It is finding your cached source numpy package (as opposed to binary wheel).

You can:

1. Delete it from the cache.
   or
2. Explicitely install with `--only-binary` which will force pip to download a binary wheel.

Comment: Sorry, I think I added this note probably as you were typing, but I nuked the pip cache and still am seeing the "cached" numpy (even searching my whole drive for numpy I can't find it).  I also tried this solution to force binary and it says it can't find a matching distro.  Added this to the question

Comment: what is your python version? what is your pip version?

Comment: in "nuked", have u tried `python -m pip cache purge`?

Comment: I hadn't done that, nuked the files from the drive itself.  Running that command did remove 58 files.  But still got the same result when trying to install numpy again

Comment: One theory I have is that the "cached version" it's looking for 1.20 which [doesn't have wheels out yet](https://numpy.org/news/) so I don't know why it's not looking for 1.19

Comment: Still no dice :(. I think I'm going to try nuking the drive and see what happens

Comment: Even nuking the drive didn't help (also spoilers it's a [real pain on M1 Macs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408876/m1-mac-clean-install-getting-stuck-at-create-a-computer-account/410064#comment579701_410064) ).  So not sure what else to try here

Comment: For sanity check, I would try to do this on isolated environmrnt using `pytrhon -m venv isolated`

Comment: I am using an isolated environment.  My env was created with `python3 -m venv py3`

Answer (score 1):

This warked for me on my M1, using pip from python 3.92 virtualenv:

```
pip install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 numpy
```

It avoids the [pep517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517) problematic build

Answer (score 0):

I won't call this **THE** answer but an answer I've gotten to work is the [Anaconda Navigator](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/)

It has a visual installer that worked out of the box on an M1 mac.  Additionally, when I used the navigator to kick off a terminal with ipython activated, the commands given worked and the resulting environment had `numpy` and `pandas` working.

Still looking for a proper native M1 solution