# Using pip to download library fails at building dependencies

Tags: pip, mingw-w64, msys2

I have a problem every time I try to download something using pip. Both pip and Setuptools are fully up to date on my computer.
When I try to download "`pip install scikit-learn`" or "`pip install -U matplotlib`", I get the same error when downloading the build dependencies.
I am on a Windows computer, and I simply want to use `pip` to install `scikit-learn` and other libraries, but It never passes the build dependencies part.

```
PS C:\Users\zaida\Documents\ML> pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.3.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [70 lines of output]
      Ignoring oldest-supported-numpy: markers 'python_version != "3.10" or platform_system != "Windows" or platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.33
        Using cached Cython-0.29.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.22.3
        Using cached numpy-1.22.3.zip (11.5 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [40 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\wang\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\wang\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "C:\wang\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            backend = _build_backend()
          File "C:\wang\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
            obj = import_module(mod_path)
          File "C:\wang\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\zaida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dpsds_li\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
            monkey.patch_all()
          File "C:\Users\zaida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dpsds_li\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
            patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
          File "C:\Users\zaida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dpsds_li\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
            patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
          File "C:\Users\zaida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dpsds_li\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
            mod = import_module(mod_name)
          File "C:\wang\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\zaida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dpsds_li\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
            raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
        distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
      Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1
     
      See above for output.
     
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with installing a newer version of Microsoft [Visual C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools). Visual Studio 2019 or newer should work.

As an alternative approach, if possible, use pre-built wheels for `numpy` (and other packages that require compilation) to avoid the need to compile them on your machine. This can be done by ensuring your `pip` is up to date and your Python version is compatible with available pre-built wheels. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67712882/6309).

If pip continues to fail, consider using a Python distribution like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download), which comes with most of these scientific libraries pre-installed and could handle dependencies more smoothly.

Comment: Used Anaconda pip isn't working